# Integral with Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory

How do I calculate this integral?
$$\int_{X} { {\ln x}\over{\cos(x^2)}}1_{(0,+\infty)} \lambda (dx) $$
Are there any formulas or theorems that will help?

Comment: It diverges at $+\infty$, are you sure there is no error ?

Comment: Yes it was mistake, I corrected.

Comment: And what is $X$ ?

Comment: All the space, that's what we write in our lectures.

Comment: But $X=\mathbb{R}$, $X=[-2,+\infty[$, $X=\mathbb{Q}$ ? It really depends on what is $X$. Here I assume that $X=\mathbb{R}$ but the integral then diverges as I said before.

Comment: $$ X =  \mathbb{R}_{+} $$ I wrote it with the characteristic function.

Comment: Then the integral diverges because of the $+\infty$ bound.

Comment: maybe to make it clear $|\cos(x^2)|\le 1\implies \left|\frac{\ln(x)}{\cos(x^2)}\right|\ge |\ln(x)|$ which goes to infinity at infinity so integral cannot converge (inners of the integral should go to $0$).

Comment: so the limit of the function goes to infinity so the integral is not well defined, right?